# how to change to connection string in web.config dynamically

Tags: c#, web-config

I defind the connection string in web.config

```
     <ConnectionStrings>
 <add name="student" connectionString="Server=student;Max Pool Size=300;Initial Catalog=studentDB;User ID=student;Password=st123dent;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
     </Connectionstrings>
```

how can i change the connection string dynamically in c#

Comment: do you want to change the connection string you are using on the page or are you wanting to change the connection string in the web.config file?

Comment: What is the usage context? I suspect that you may want to use [ASP.Net Membership](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx). I apologize if I'm wrong.

Comment: change connection string in web.config

Comment: my applicatin is used by different clinets each have their own db,when user logsin depending on their domain name,port address we will retrieve the conn string from db (nearly 250 connection strings) that is used to connect to DB.is this is a good way ? or any other best practice?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Configuration is read only so you can not do it in obvious way like

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["student"].ConnectionString = "new value";
```

This raises  [System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationerrorsexception.aspx) exception which saying that "Configuration is read only".

Here is a trick using reflection to reset readOnly attribute of configuration element.
See this article for full details [Programmatically setting a connectionString property](http://david.gardiner.net.au/2008/09/programmatically-setting.html)

Code snippet:

```
var settings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[ 0 ];
var fi = typeof(ConfigurationElement).GetField(
              "_bReadOnly", 
              BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
fi.SetValue(settings, false);
settings.ConnectionString = "Data Source=Something";
```

BTW, why you need change it the configuration? I'm feeling that you'are trying to solve some problem in wrong way.

Comment: my applicatin is used by different clinets each have their own db,when user logsin depending on their domain name,port address we will retrieve the conn string from db (nearly 250 connection strings) that is used to connect to DB.is this is a good way ? or any other best practice?

Answer (score 3):

You can open your Web.Config file for reading and writing using `WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration` or `WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration`.  And provided you have write permission you'll be able to make modifications such as changing the connection string.

This surely has to be better than using reflection to modify a private field.

Modifying web.config will then recycle the web application, so this isn't suitable for letting users make changes to web.config - though it could be used in specific scenarios such as deployment.

Example:

```
var configurationFileInfo = new FileInfo(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
var vdm = new VirtualDirectoryMapping(configurationFileInfo.DirectoryName, true, configurationFileInfo.Name);
var wcfm = new WebConfigurationFileMap();
wcfm.VirtualDirectories.Add("/", vdm);
Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenMappedWebConfiguration(wcfm, "/");

ConnectionStringsSection section = config.GetSection("connectionStrings") 
                         as ConnectionStringsSection;
if (section != null)
{
    ... modify the section ...
    config.Save();
}
```

Comment: how to modify it..i used Section.Connectionstring= "datasource", it gives me error

Comment: @Gani, something like `section.ConnectionStrings["MyName"].ConnectionString = "..."`.

Answer (score 1):

in Web Confige put this code

```
<add name="yourconnectionname" connectionString="Data Source={0};Initial Catalog={1};User ID={2};Password={3}" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

in your connection put this code

```
 string ScrtCon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourconnectionname"].ToString();
ScrtCon = string.Format(ScrtCon, "Server Name","Data base Name",  "Database User Name", "Database password");
```

Answer (score 0):

If a user is able to change the value of the Setting, then the web.config file is the wrong place to store the setting.

You should check out a User Scoped value in a Settings file instead.

[MSDN - Using Settings in C](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869.aspx)

When using settings like this, changing the value at runtime is easy:

```
Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionStringName = "New Connection String";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NameSpace

```
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Configuration;


void ConfigurnewConnectionString(string server, string database, string userid, string password)
    {


    string str = "server=" + server + ";database=" + database + "; User ID=" + userid + "; Password=" + password + "";
    //Configuration myConfiguration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    //str = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["myKey"];
    //myConfiguration.Save();
    System.Configuration.Configuration Config1 = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    ConnectionStringsSection conSetting = (ConnectionStringsSection)Config1.GetSection("connectionStrings");
    ConnectionStringSettings StringSettings = new ConnectionStringSettings("conn", "Data Source=" + server + ";Database=" + database + ";User ID=" + userid + ";Password=" + password + ";");
    conSetting.ConnectionStrings.Remove(StringSettings);
    conSetting.ConnectionStrings.Add(StringSettings);
    Config1.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    //Configuration myConfiguration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
    //myConfiguration.AppSettings.Settings.Item("myKey").Value = txtmyKey.Text;
    //myConfiguration.Save();
}
```