# "Non-static field requires a target" on Deployment version

Tags: c#, connection-string

Sometime ago I had a problem with the db's connection string. I solved it following this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/7692708/1616222 (thank you)

When I'm debugging all is working properly but when I deployed the application and installed it when it reaches :

```
fi.SetValue(settings, false);
```

It throws the exception "Non-static field requires a target".

I'm using .NET Famework 3.5, and I'm not allow to change it.

Answer (score 3):

That means that your `settings` variable is `null`. So... make it not `null`. At a guess: in production the connection string doesn't exist in the config file.